# Run Python script from a remote machine in another one going over a ssh jump first

Tags: python

I would like to run a python script from a remote machine in another machine  but I have to  go first  through a (sshjump) to reach this machine.

I had two ideas:

1) Extend what works for one  machine. 
I came with that: 
***cat something.py | ssh jumphost |  ssh remotemachine_to_reach 'python3'*** 
This option unfortunately doesn't work .

2) Use the library jumpssh .  But As far I understood I can pass just bash command.

3) Subprocess ? but i didn't really investigate that path .

If you know what to do or where to look let me know it would be  would be really cool .

Comment: have you tested paramiko? (http://www.paramiko.org/)

Comment: Are you using powershell for this? linux terminal? or is this a python script that runs the python scripts on another machine?

Comment: I am using Linux shell ( Debian)

Comment: I am open to any suggestions as long I get the Job done....

Comment: My work around:  CHECK with ip a s  if you have an  eth an internal network between the remote machine . You might not have to go through the jumpssh  if you ssh in the intern network.   Then was my problem solved ......